# Growing Cherry Trees from Seeds

Tags: germination, cherries

last August I bought some cherries, removed the seeds (about a dozen), washed them, and tucked them in the refrigerator for the winter (7 months). Now that spring-time is here, I planted those seeds in a little pot about two weeks ago and I have yet to see any action. I put a little bit of water in the soil about every other day just to keep the soil moist. Now that it's gotten warm, I also put the containers out in the sun to warm them up.

Am I doing this correctly? How long does it usually take for the plants to show themselves?

Comment: Where did you buy the original cherries? If they came from a large supermarket, they may have been in refrigerated storage for a long time before you bought them and germination may be poor. Ideally, you want cherries picked fresh from a tree. In any case, wait several months (not weeks) before you decide they aren't going to grow.

Comment: They may be hybrids , that is , not produce exactly the same fruits.  Fine if you want to grow seeds . But if you want cherries you will save several years by going to a garden shop ,or other, and buying a tree. Depending on your location , you may still get bare root trees by mail.

Comment: @alephzero, yes I purchased them from a supermarket.

Comment: @blacksmith37, I just want to get the thing growing. I don't care that much about the fruit.

Comment: I just planted some cherry seeds myself tonight! From what I've read, it's really difficult to get tree seeds to germinate successfully.

Comment: @moinudin if I get mine to germinate, I'll let you know. I threw in some beet seeds into the container to see if anything would happen with those and not even two days, boom. :)

Comment: @moinudin I pulled a seed out of the ground and discovered that the shell had cracked almost all the way around. I used a knife to remove it, and then planted the inside back in the ground. A month later, I have a tiny tree growing.